# Algorithm to calculate point prize and return ordened

Tags: algorithm

I'm implementing an algorithm for a point prize system that should calculate the score of each person. i.e.:

- Person A invited Person B;
- Person A invited Person C;
- Person B invited Person D;
- Person D invited Person E.

And the result will be:

- Person A has 12.5 points (5 points because invited B and C, and 2.5 points because B has invited D);
- Person B has 12.5 points (5 points because invited D);
- Person B has 12.5 points (5 points because invited D);

What would be the appropiate algorithm to write this function? I was thinking about to use Djikstra but Djikstra would be great if i was writing a function to find a path between two persons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is basic recursion, right?  A more advanced algorithm would be useful if your question was "*who has the most points*".  That kind of question could be optimised.

If there's a *lot* of data to process, I'd recommend considering de-normalising your datastore by adding a cache of points accumulated.  It'll save you having to chew through an ever-increasing collection of numbers every time.

Pick depth or breadth first and try to write your code in such a manner that memory isn't leaked (notably stack overflows or ever-growing arrays).

Comment: I've implemented two solutions. The first is a Tree-like where each node has an identifier and a list of children nodes. The other solution i've did was simple: just applying map funciona. What should be more "correct"?

Comment: All i need is to read a list and calcular score like the example i wrote. I think this is simple.

Comment: Tree-like is faster then recurssion that i've wrote